# programmatically simulate user input from one Android application to another

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to programmatically simulate user input from one android application to another ? I'd like to create android application that will be send commands to another. For example - user touch screen action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible using one of these two approaches:

- Root your device

  - Direct injection to /dev/input/eventX
  - Using InputManager.injectTouchEvent()
  - Using WindowManager.injectPointerEvent()
- Create an `AccessibilityService`. Notice that this is not guaranteed to work with all third-party apps.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `AccessiblityService` since Android 4.0. Details [in my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28171052/986533).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, this would be too high security risk. Maybe add what you actually would like your app to do?

If this is for testing then this can be achived with test framework, for example you can use uiautomator:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html